# Oracle SQL - Generate Unique sAMAccountName

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to use Oracle SQL to generate unique sAMAccountName for users. The logic to generate the unique name is the First letter of first name + entire Last Name.

If the combination already exists, append 1 at the end of the unique name.
If the second combination already exists, increment till uniqueness is achieved.

For example, 5 users named "Tom Kelly" and 3 users named "Tom Ke" will have the following unique names:

1. TKelly
2. TKelly1
3. TKelly2
4. TKelly3
5. TKelly4
6. TKe
7. TKe1
8. TKe2

I have written a procedure for this but it's not working completely. I think the logic needs to be updated in this query of the procedure:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Custom_Unique_Name,-1,1) INTO lastletter 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT Custom_Unique_Name FROM 
P_USERS WHERE Custom_Unique_Name= item.tempid2 AND 
user_id <> item.user_id ORDER BY Custom_Unique_Name 
DESC) WHERE ROWNUM<=1);
```

The read-only table `P_USERS` contains all the users with a primary key as `"user_id"` and the unique name is stored in the attribute `"Custom_Unique_Name"`

After calculating the unique name, the attribute `"PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME"` in the master user table `"T_MASTER_USERS"` needs to be updated. This table's primary key is also `"user_id"` which holds the same value as in the read-only table `"P_USERS"`

```
   DECLARE
    lastletter varchar2(10);
    anyexists varchar2(10);
    lastfive varchar2(10);
    CURSOR c_length IS SELECT SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)||(last_name) as 
    tempid2,LENGTH(last_name) as lengthln, user_id, Custom_Unique_Name 
    FROM P_USERS;
    status varchar2(10);
    BEGIN
     FOR item in c_length
      LOOP
        EXIT WHEN c_length%notfound;
        lastletter:=0;
        SELECT NVL(Custom_Unique_Name,0) INTO status FROM P_USERS 
        WHERE USER_ID=item.user_id; 
        IF status <> '0' THEN /* Checks if the person already has a 
        unique id */
         NULL;   /* If yes, then do nothing and exit the program */
        ELSE
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO anyexists FROM (SELECT 
            Custom_Unique_Name FROM P_USERS 
            WHERE Custom_Unique_Name = item.tempid2 AND user_id <> 
            item.user_id);
            IF anyexists=0 THEN     /* Check if unique id exists for 
            the user. If not, then assign unique_id to the user */
                UPDATE T_MASTER_USERS SET 
                PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME=item.tempid2 WHERE 
                user_id=item.user_id;
                ELSE
                 SELECT SUBSTR(Custom_Unique_Name,-1,1) INTO lastletter 
                 FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT Custom_Unique_Name FROM 
                 P_USERS WHERE Custom_Unique_Name= item.tempid2 AND 
                 user_id <> item.user_id ORDER BY Custom_Unique_Name 
                 DESC) WHERE ROWNUM<=1);
                 IF LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(lastletter, ' 
                 +-.0123456789',' '))) > 0 THEN /* Checks if the count 
                 of equivalent unique names if a number. If not, append 
                 1*/
                    UPDATE T_MASTER_USERS SET 
                    PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME=item.tempid2||'1' WHERE 
                    user_id=item.user_id;
                    ELSE
                     lastletter:=lastletter+1;
                     UPDATE T_MASTER_USERS SET 
                     PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME=item.tempid2||lastletter WHERE 
                     user_id=item.user_id;
                  END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END;
```

Comment: I built a system like this once before, I found it _much_ easier to handle this in client code for whatever app I was building... generate a string there, and try an insert against a column with a UNIQUE constraint, and keep iterating on failure until it succeeds. More recently, I've wanted system to be sure there is [either a manual human review, a choice is offered, or the username is a valid e-mail address from an outside system](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/z0t3x/unfortunate_email_address/) before creating the name.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SQL> create table users
  2    (username varchar2(20) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_un (par_first_name in varchar2,
  2                                    par_last_name  in varchar2)
  3  is
  4    l_username users.username%type;
  5    l_letter   users.username%type;
  6    l_digit    users.username%type;
  7    retval     users.username%type;
  8  begin
  9    l_username := upper(substr(par_first_name, 1, 1) || par_last_name);
 10
 11    select max(regexp_substr(u.username, '^\w+')) l_letter,
 12           max(regexp_substr(u.username, '\d+$')) l_digit
 13      into l_letter,
 14           l_digit
 15      from users u
 16      where u.username like l_username ||'%'
 17        and (   substr(u.username, length(l_username) + 1, 1) between '1' and '9'
 18             or (    regexp_substr(u.username, '\d$') is null
 19                 and substr(u.username, length(l_username) + 1, 1) is null
 20                )
 21            )
 22        and (   to_number(regexp_substr(username, '\d$')) =
 23                 (select max(to_number(regexp_substr(u1.username, '\d$')))
 24                  from users u1
 25                  where u1.username like l_username ||'%'
 26                  and (   substr(u1.username, length(l_username) + 1, 1) between '1' and '9'
 27                       or (    regexp_substr(u1.username, '\d$') is null
 28                           and substr(u1.username, length(l_username) + 1, 1) is null
 29                          )
 30                      )
 31                 )
 32              or regexp_substr(u.username, '\d$') is null
 33             );
 34
 35    if l_letter is null then
 36       retval := upper(l_username);
 37    else
 38       retval := upper(l_username || to_char(to_number(nvl(l_digit, 0)) + 1));
 39    end if;
 40
 41    dbms_output.put_line('l_username = ' || l_username||', letter = '|| l_letter||
 42                         ', digit = '||l_digit ||', new username = ' || retval);
 43    insert into users (username) values (retval);
 44  end;
 45  /

Procedure created.
```

What does it do?

`SELECT` (at line 11) searches for existing usernames that

- look like a new username (which is composed of the first letter of the first name and the whole last name) (line 16)
- contains a number at the end (line 17)
- or there's no number at all (lines 18, 19)
- but, if there is a number there, select MAX number (line 23)
- if such a username doesn't exist, return its default value (line 36)
- if it exists, add `1` to the MAX number and attach it to the default username value (line 38)

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Kelly');
l_username = TKELLY, letter = , digit = , new username = TKELLY

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Kelly');
l_username = TKELLY, letter = TKELLY, digit = , new username = TKELLY1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Kelly');
l_username = TKELLY, letter = TKELLY1, digit = 1, new username = TKELLY2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Ke');
l_username = TKE, letter = , digit = , new username = TKE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Ke');
l_username = TKE, letter = TKE, digit = , new username = TKE1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Kelly');
l_username = TKELLY, letter = TKELLY2, digit = 2, new username = TKELLY3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Ke');
l_username = TKE, letter = TKE1, digit = 1, new username = TKE2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_un('Tom', 'Ke');
l_username = TKE, letter = TKE2, digit = 2, new username = TKE3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From users;

USERNAME
--------------------
TKE
TKE1
TKE2
TKE3
TKELLY
TKELLY1
TKELLY2
TKELLY3

8 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Anonymous block for your scenario:

```
  create table P_USERS
     (first_name varchar2(20),
     last_name   varchar2(20),
     user_id   number);

  insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Kelly',1);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Kelly',2);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Kelly',3);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Kelly',4);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Kelly',5);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Ke',6);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Ke',7);
 insert into P_USERS values ('Tom','Ke',8);
 commit;

 create table T_MASTER_USERS
 ( user_id   number,
 PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME varchar2(20));

  insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (1,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (2,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (3,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (4,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (5,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (6,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (7,NULL);
 insert into T_MASTER_USERS values (8,NULL);
 commit;


 DECLARE
    cursor uniq_grp is SELECT SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)||(last_name) as 
    tempid2 ,count(*) as CNT
    FROM P_USERS
    group by SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)||(last_name);

    cursor concat_names is SELECT SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)||(last_name) as 
    tempid2, user_id 
    FROM P_USERS;

    V_CNT number;

 BEGIN

    FOR C1 in uniq_grp

    LOOP

    FOR C2 IN concat_names
    LOOP
    IF C2.tempid2=C1.tempid2 THEN 
     V_CNT := c1.CNT -1;
    UPDATE T_MASTER_USERS SET 
      PRIMARY_UNIQUE_NAME=c2.tempid2||V_CNT WHERE 
       user_id=C2.user_id;
       c1.cnt := V_CNT;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

create or replace procedure generate_unique(par_first_name in varchar2,par_last_name  in varchar2)
  (par_first_name in varchar2,par_last_name  in varchar2)
 is
 l_username users.username%type;
 l_letter   users.username%type;

begin

```
 l_username := upper(substr(par_first_name, 1, 1) || par_last_name); 

 dbms_output.put_line('l_username = ' || l_username );
```

SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(USERNAME),'[^0-9]', '')) IS NULL

```
            THEN l_username 

            ELSE l_username 

                    || 

                    (MAX(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(USERNAME),'[^0-9]', ''))+1) 

    END into l_letter FROM    USERS WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(USERNAME),l_username||'[0-9]*$');
```

dbms_output.put_line('unique userid  is ' || l_letter);
end;

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code, and fix your code block formatting.